# Airflow - trigger a specific task from external

Tags: airflow

In Apache Airflow, let's say I want to set up a DAG that has 3 tasks.

Task A
Task B
Task C

When the DAG gets scheduled, I want task A to run, followed by Task B (when A completes).
However, I want task C to only run when some external code triggers it (and it shouldn't poll and wait for an external condition to be satisfied; I want it to wait until it receives an external request to start execution, but only if A and B are completed).
I also don't want to create another DAG for task C.

Is this possible? How to set up please? Will it require another task between B and C?

Thanks for any advice on how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is to have two tasks leading into task `C`, so for example:

```
A >> [B, x] >> C
```

Where `x` is a new task. Then you can set `x` to be your other trigger condition from somewhere external.

For example if you're waiting for a certain file to be delivered for `C` to execute, create `x` as a BranchOperator, and only return `C` from it if the file exists.

Comment: Thanks - but this means in x I have to poll/check the source. I would like it so that the airflow task x (or just task C itself) gets triggered (for example via the rest API).

Comment: @Vince While it's not best-practice, you could create a task that loops and waits for a certain time (for example 23 hours if you want this daily), then use the REST API to set the task instance to successful. Once that's successful, `C` would trigger. If it's not successful after 23 hours, the DAG would fail. See "Set a state of task instances" here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/post_set_task_instances_state

Comment: Thank you! I think that’s worth a try.